# Fast way to compute row by row matrix correlation

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

I have two very large matrices (228453x460) and I want to compute correlation between rows.

```
for i=1:228453
    if(vec1_preprocess(i,1))
        for j=1:228453
            df = effdf(vec1_preprocess(i,:)',vec2_preprocess(j,:)');
            corr_temp = corr(vec1_preprocess(i,:)', vec2_preprocess(j,:)');
            p = calculate_p(corr_temp, df);
            temp = (meanVec(i)+p)/2;
            meanVec(i) = temp;
        end
        disp(i);
    end
end
```

This takes ~1day. Is there a direct way to compute this?

**Edit:** Code for `effdf`

```
function df = effdf(ts1,ts2);
%function df = effdf(ts1,ts2);

    ts1=ts1-mean(ts1);
    ts2=ts2-mean(ts2);
    N=length(ts1);

    ac1=xcorr(ts1); 
    ac1=ac1/max(ac1); % normalized autocorrelation
    ac1=ac1(((length(ac1)+3)/2):((length(ac1)+3)/2+floor(N/4)));

    ac2=xcorr(ts2); 
    ac2=ac2/max(ac2); % normalized autocorrelation 
    ac2=ac2(((length(ac2)+3)/2):((length(ac2)+3)/2+floor(N/4)));

    df = 1/((1/N)+(2/N)*sum(((N-(1:length(ac1)))/N)'.*ac1.*ac2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't post the code, I assume that your custom functions `calculate_p` and `effdf` are perfectly optimized and don't represent the bottleneck of your script. Let's focus on what we have.

The first problem I see is:

```
if (vec1_preprocess(i,1))
```

A check over `228453` iterations can sensibly increase the running time. Hence, extract only the matrix rows that don't contain a `0` in the first column and perform your calculations on those:

```
idx = vec1_preprocess(:,1) ~= 0;
vec1_preprocess = vec1_preprocess(idx,:);

for i = 1:size(vec1_preprocess,1)
    % ...
end
```

The second problem is `corr`. It seems like you are computing p-values also, using `calculate_p`. Why don't you use the buil-in p-values returned by the function as second output argument?

```
[c,p] = corr(A,B);
```

Alternatively, if Pearson's correlation is what you are looking for, you could replace `corr` with `corrcoef` to see if it produces a better performance.

Last but not least (in fact it's the most important thing): is there any reason why you are performing this computation row by row instead of running it on the whole matrices?

Comment: I have edited the code for `effdf`. 

`calculate_p` function is not the same as built-in p-values returned by the `corr` function. 

Since, I have to manually calculate `effdf` and p-values, I am perfoming computations row by row and not on the whole matrices. Let me know if same can be done on the whole matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corr.html), you'll see that `corr` computes the correlation between columns, not rows.

To convert rows into columns and columns into rows, simply transpose the matrix:

```
tmp1 = vec1_preprocess';
tmp2 = vec2_preprocess';
C = corr(tmp1,tmp2);
```

Comment: While computing `corr` I am transposing the matrix.

`corr_temp = corr(vec1_preprocess(i,:)', vec2_preprocess(j,:)');`

Comment: @ArihantJain What I'm suggesting though is to apply `corr` to the whole matrix, not row by row. That will be much, much faster. I ignored the call to the function `effdf` because you didn't have its code at the time. I'm sure that the same applies there.